# TreeView with multiple levels

Tags: wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

Of the following code

```
<TreeView Name="tree" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllNotes}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Note}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListIssuesType}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SoftwareVersion}" Margin="2" />
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:IssueType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IssueNames}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IssueTypeName}" Margin="2" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:IssueType}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IssueTypeName}" />                
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

I get the error:

> "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'DataTemplateKey(ReleaseNotes_Window.Models.IssueType)'  Key being added: 'DataTemplateKey(ReleaseNotes_Window.Models.IssueType)'"

Comment: You have 2 `DataTemplate` for same type (`IssueType`). Remove one, most likely the latter

Answer (score 0):

When you put something into a `ResourceDictionary` it either needs an explicit `x:Key` or the key will be determined by the `DictionaryKeyPropertyAttribute` applied on the class.

For `DataTemplate` it is the following:

```
[DictionaryKeyProperty("DataTemplateKey")]
public class DataTemplate : FrameworkTemplate
```

This will depend on the `DataType`.

Because you have:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:IssueType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IssueNames}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IssueTypeName}" Margin="2" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:IssueType}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IssueTypeName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Both with `DataType="{x:Type m:IssueType}"`, that's why the program fails.

Use an additional `x:Key` for one of the `DataTemplate`s and reference it as a `StaticResource` where you're planning to use it.