# WPF: The key is already defined in this scope

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, types

I'm working with TreeView and I want two ObservableCollections (KategorijeLekovi and KategorijeRadnici) to be shown under a node (which is an object of class Apoteka). I get this error: "The key is already defined in this scope." and it reffers to the second DataType="{x:Type local:Apoteka}". However, if I delete this DataType, I get a different error: "All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them."

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="trv1" >
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Apoteka}" ItemsSource="{Binding KategorijeLekovi}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Naziv}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Apoteka}" ItemsSource="{Binding KategorijeRadnici}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Naziv}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
...
```

Comment: You can not have an automatically chosen DataTemplate for the same DataType within a ResourceDictionary. You are apparently trying to use two different child item collections in the DataTemplate for a TreeView item node. That does not work. You have to have a single child item collection, where the child items may be of different type. So for "*I'm working with TreeView and I want two ObservableCollections (KategorijeLekovi and KategorijeRadnici) to be shown under a node.*" - this is simply not how TreeView works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for answering, I managed to solve it with your help. Instead of having two ObservableCollections I made one, which had items from both KategorijeLekovi and KategorijeRadnici

Comment: Thank a contributor in a reply to their answer Instead of stating your gratitude in a new answer-post.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use the x:key attribute

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="LekoviTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Apoteka}" ItemsSource="{Binding KategorijeLekovi}">


<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="RadniciTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Apoteka}" ItemsSource="{Binding KategorijeRadnici}">
```

Then set it in the tree view,

```
<TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LekoviTemplate}" ...
```

or

```
<TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RadniciTemplate}" ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I did that and now I get this error: "The property "key" does not exist in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" namespace."

Comment: When I put "Key" instead of "key" and run it, it just shows two lines saying "asdf.Apoteka" (asdf is the name of namespace)

Comment: @DataType You need to explicitly refer the key where you use it. This will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/34909740/3137337